# Creating two C# class definitions with a driver to test classes, but not sure why so many errors?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class

I am new to C# and was asked to create two class definitions (customer and order) using partial code and with the suggested class names, methods, contructors and following an example.  I am not sure  why I am getting so many errors when I build/debug?

After this is finished, I need to create another program that builds onto this one. Our instructor also asked us not to use validation...

Some of my most common errors are:

`expected: ;` (in a place in my code where I believe there should *not* be a semi-colon and

`Error      "Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct`.

Here is my code:

```
public class clsOrder
{
    //declare class variables
   protected string cstrDescription;
   protected int cintQuantity;
   protected decimal cdecPrice;
   protected decimal cdecExtendedPrice;

   //shared variables
   static decimal cdecTotalPrice;
   static int cintTotalCount; 


    //declare constructors

   public clsOrder();

   }
   public clsOrde r(string strDescription,
   int intQuantity, decimal decPrice)
    }
   //declare property methods
   {    
   this.Description = string strDescription;
   this.Quantity = int intQuantity;
   this.Price = decimal decPrice;

    //declare read-only properties
    public decimal ExtendedPrice
    }

      public string Description
     {
      get
      {
       return strDescription;
        }
        set 
        {
        strDescription = value;
         }
      }

      public int Quantity
      {
       get
       {
       return intQuantity;
       }
       set
       {
        intQuantity = value;
        }
     }

       public decimal Price
       {
        get
        {
        return decPrice;
         }
        set
        {
        decPrice = value;
         }
       }
        get
        {
            return cdecExtendedPrice;
        }
    }

    //declare Shared (static) ReadOnly Properites
    public static decimal TotalPrice
    {
        get
        {
            return cdecTotalPrice;
        }
    }

    public static int TotalCount
    {
        get
        {
            return cintTotalCount;
        }
    }

    //declare supporting methods
    public void calcExtendedPrice()
    {
        cdecExtendedPrice = cintQuantity * cdecPrice;
    }

    public void accumulateTotals()
    {
        cdecTotalPrice += cdecExtendedPrice;
        cintTotalCount += 1;
    }

    public static void resetTotals()
    {
        cdecTotalPrice = 0;
        cintTotalCount = 0;
    }

    }//end of Class
}//end of namespace
```

And

```
 public class clsCustomer
    {
        //declare class variables
        private string cstrName;
        private string cstrStreet;
        private string cstrCity;
        private string cstrState;
        private string cstrZip;

        //declare constructors
     public class clsCustomer() 
     }
     public clsCustomer(string strName, 
     string strStreet, string strCity, 
     string strState, string strZip) 
     }

      //declare property methods
    {
    this.Name = cstrName;
    this.Street = cstrStreet;
    this.City = cstrCity;
    this.State = cstrState;
    this.Zip = cstrZip;
    }

    public string Name
  {
   get
  {
   return cstrName;
  }
  set
{
 cstrName = value;
  }
}

public string Street
{
get
{
return cstrStreet;
}
set
{
cstrStreet = value;
  }
}

public string City
{
get
{
return cstrCity;
}
set
{
cstrCity = value;
  }
}

public string State
{
get
  {
return cstrState;
}
set 
  {
cstrState = value;
  }
}

public string Zip
{
get
{
return cstrZip;
}
set
{
cstringZip = value;
  }
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Way too much code with way too many errors. Would take too long to hunt everything down. There's already a `public clsOrder();` (don't put a ; there) and `public class clsCustomer()}` (wrong way for the bracket) visible. But way too much stuff. You're also not following multiple C# conventions and have an horrible indentation, which makes everything harder to sift through. You should start from scratch and build it up little by little IMO.

Comment: Your constructor is missing opening curly bracket { . constructor cannot have keyword class.  I have fixed your last bit of code. You can compare with your logic and see what you did wrong. http://csharppad.com/gist/cec93b7b77b328eb07e9

Comment: Your `{`s and `}`s don't seem to match up. See [Scopes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa691132.aspx). Also, ` public class clsCustomer() }` is not how one declares a [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ace5hbzh.aspx). And I can't even imagine what you mean by "declare property methods".

Comment: You should start to write it again with out copy paste.

Comment: Never get panic because of the error count. Most of the times errors are interrelated. If you fix one 2-3 of others will get resolved. For example, that semicolon after constructor () is causing errors during code parsing down the line.

Comment: Double-click on an error in the error window in Visual Studio after you try to build.  This should place your cursor on the line of code that has that error.